# Elasticsearch - Filter where (one of nested array) and (all of nested array)

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, nested

***TL;DR*** - How do I check whether **one-of** and **all-of** a nested array meet specified criteria?

I have a `document`. Each `document` has an array of nested `outer` objects, who themselves have a list of nested `inner` objects. I need to perform a filter for all documents where **at least one of** the document's `outer` nested objects match. When I say match, I mean that **all** the `outer` nested objects' `inner` objects match in some way. Here's an example mapping for reference;

```
{ "document" : {
    "properties" : {
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "outer" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "inner" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "match" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              },
              "type" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
    }}}}}}
}
```

If the document has no `outer`/`inner` objects it is considered to match. But to make things worse the inner objects need to be considered to match differently depending on the `type` in a kind of conditional logic manner (eg `CASE` in SQL). For example, if the `type` were the term `"Country"` then `inner` object would be considered to match if the `match` were a specified country code such as `ES`. A document may have `inner` objects of varying `type` and there is not guarantee that specific types will exist.

Coming from a imperative (Java) programming background I am having incredible trouble figuring out how to implement this kind of filtering. Nothing I can think of even vaguely matches this behaviour. Thus far all I have is the filtered query;

```
"filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_all" : { }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : {
            "missing" : {
              "field" : "outer.inner.type"
            }
    }}}}
}
```

So, the question is...

How can I filter to documents who have **at least one** `outer` object which has **all** `inner` objects matching based on the `type` of `inner` object?

Further details By Request -

### Example Document JSON

```
{
    "name":"First",
    "outer":[
        {
            "inner":[
                {"match":"ES","type":"Country"},
                {"match":"Elite","type":"Market"}
            ]
        },{
            "inner":[
                {"match":"GBR","type":"Country"},
                {"match":"1st Class","type":"Market"},
                {"match":"Admin","type":"Role"}
            ]
        }
    ],
    "lockVersion":0,"sourceId":"1"
}
```

The above example should come through the filter if we were to provide `"1st Class"` market **and** the country `"GRB"` because the second of the two `outer` objects would be considered a match because both `inner` objects match. If, however, we provided the country country `"GRB"` and the market `"Elite"` then we would not have this document returned because neither of the `outer` objects would have bother of their `inner` objects match in their entirety. If we wanted the second `outer` object to match then all three `inner` would need to match. Take note that there is an extra `type` in the third `inner`. This leads to a situation where **if** a type exists **then** it needs to have a match for it **else** it doesn't need to match because it is absent.

Comment: Could you post some example data, maybe in a gist or something? It needs to include enough variety to cover your various cases. I think I might know how to solve this, but I don't want to spend all morning constructing dummy data to test it.

Comment: @SloanAhrens - I've posted up a single example document with some details, and if that's still not enough let me know and I'll throw together some more examples. I'm not actually using production data/mapping in the question above so I will have to manually convert the data to match the question.

Comment: Nope, that did it, I think.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### One of Nested Array

Having **one of** a nested array matching some criteria turns out to be very simple. A [nested filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-nested-filter.html) evaluates to matching/true if any of the array of nested objects match the specified inner filters. For example, given an array of `outer` objects where one of those objects has a field `match` with the value `"matching"` the following would be considered true.

```
"nested": {
   "path": "outer",
   "filter": {
       "term" : { "match" : "matching" } 
   }
}
```

The above will be considered true/matching if **one of** the nested `outer` objects has a field called `match` with the value `"matching"`.

### All of Nested Array

Having a nested filter only be considered matching if **all of** the nested objects in an array match is more interesting. In fact, it's impossible. But given that it is considered matching if only one of the nested objects match a filter we can reverse the logic and say "If **none** of the nested objects **don't** match" to achieve what we need. For example, given an array of nested `outer.inner` objects where all of those objects has a field `match` with the value `"matching"` the following would be considered true.

```
"not" : {
   "nested": {
      "path": "outer.inner",
      "filter": {
          "not" : {
              "term" : { "match" : "matching" } 
          }
      }
   }
}
```

The above will be considered true/matching because **none** of the nested `outer.inner` objects **don't** (double negative) have a field called `match` with the value `"matching"`. This, of course, is the same as **all of** the nested `inner` objects having a field `match` with the value `"matching"`.

### Missing Any Nested Objects

You can't check whether a field containing nested objects is missing using the traditional [missing filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-filter.html). This is because nested objects aren't actually **in** the document at all, they are stored somewhere else. As such [missing filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-filter.html) will always be considered true. What you can do however, is check that a `match_all` filter returns no results like so;

```
"not": {
   "nested": {
      "path": "outer",
      "filter": {
          "match_all": {}
       }
    }
 }
```

This is considered true/matching if `match_all` finds no results.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

Well, it's a doozy, but this query seems to do what you want:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "outer",
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "nested": {
                              "path": "outer.inner",
                              "filter": {
                                 "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                       { "term": { "outer.inner.type": "Market" } },
                                       { "term": { "outer.inner.match": "1st Class" } }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "nested": {
                              "path": "outer.inner",
                              "filter": {
                                 "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                       { "term": { "outer.inner.type": "Country" } },
                                       { "term": { "outer.inner.match": "GBR" } }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/f554c2ad2ef2c7e6f5b94b1ddb907813370f4edc

Let me know if you need some explanation of the logic; it is kind of involved.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thank you for your help, but this wont find results that don't have any outer objects. Also, because we can't be sure specific `type` will definitely exist this wont find any document if the `Country` type is not there. I think maybe I need to put more clarifying details into my question. This does help me a lot though.

Comment: +1 - I actually figured it out in the end, but thank you again for all your help. I posted an answer with the details of what I needed.