# Elasticsearch: Find all parents where all children have a property with a specific value

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I have the current schema:

- Object `parent` with property `date` and n children `child`
- Object `child` contains a single property `foo`

I want to retrieve all `parent` where *all* `child` have their property `foo` equals to `0`

I tried different approach but whatever I do, some `parent` are retrived while one `child` has the property `foo` at `1`

Example of my query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "date": {
                            "lt": "2018-07-05T10:00:00.000Z"
                        }
                    }               
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "child",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": {
                                    "term": {
                                        "child.foo": 0
                                    }       
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with `should`, `match`, `range`... even `must_not`/`should_not`. I also tried filtering without any luck, I keep getting hits with the `foo` property at `1`.

I also tried the aggregation path but I don't understand how to apply it to my need.

**EDIT:** I looked at the possible duplicate. While it did not answer my question, it put me on the right track. My issue was that I was thinking in a SQL way, with joins and such. While I should have thought in the elastic way.

Thus, what I wanted to do could not be done. What I needed was to look for `parent` where at least one `child` had the `foo` property at 1 or more. Then, ignore these results and take the others. Thus the answer is simple: I just add to change the `must` of the nested query by a `must_not` and that was it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch - Filter where (one of nested array) and (all of nested array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608969/elasticsearch-filter-where-one-of-nested-array-and-all-of-nested-array)

Comment: Basically, must (nested all (must)) = must_not (nested at least one (must_not)).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. While the syntax is different in my case (`not` doesn't exist) I found a solution by thinking differently.

Comment: I am not sure I understand - I never mentioned `not`, only `must_not` :) Anyway, good that you got a solution. Consider posting it here for posterity.

Comment: I was talking about the link you provided ^^ in any case thanks to you I got on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in the edit of my question, the answer is fairly easy once you start thinking in the right way./

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "date": {
                            "lt": "2018-07-05T10:00:00.000Z"
                        }
                    }               
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "child",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must_not": {
                                    "term": {
                                        "child.foo": 0
                                    }       
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The trick was just to set a **must_not**

Comment: how can I create this mapping: **child.foo** using NEST fluent API?